# Play video from stream using Vlc.Dotnet for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, libvlc, vlc.dotnet

I want my WPF application to play video from a given stream. Tried to google, but didn't find any working example with the latest `Vlc.Dotnet.Wpf` version. I have installed the latest package with NuGet and here is what I have so far:

My XAML:

```
    <Vlc:VlcControl xmlns:Vlc="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf" x:Name="vlcPlayer" />
```

C# code:

```
        vlcPlayer.BeginInit();
        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\");
        vlcPlayer.EndInit();

        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("http://79.170.191.118:1935/formula55_2/stream55_2/playlist.m3u8"));
```

When I run, nothing happens. However stream works fine in Vlc Player. What are my options here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
    // Default installation path of VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows
    var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));

    this.VlcControl.SourceProvider.CreatePlayer(libDirectory/* pass your player parameters here */);
    this.VlcControl.SourceProvider.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("http://79.170.191.118:1935/formula55_2/stream55_2/playlist.m3u8"));
}
```

You will need to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows/ which is the correct way to consume libvlc libraries in .NET.

For next time, post some logs please as otherwise it's mostly guesswork. Also check out the official samples https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/tree/develop/src/Samples

Comment: When I try to do write `this.VlcControl.SourceProvider` I cannot find any `SourceProvider` property for my Vlc player. I have installed the latest version (3.0.4) using NuGet.

Comment: Clone the repo with the samples and start from there. Look at the differences from your code. Check the `using` statements

Comment: Turns out `SourceProvider` is available only in version 3.0, which is in preview. So had to download the prerelease version.